# Cocos2d v2 CCSprite Background Image dimension

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have created a new Cocos2d project and I deleted the 'Hello World' label. I have added this image (320x480 px) and tested on iPhone 4, here is the result. The image's dimensions have been reduced to 1/4th of their original size, not sure what's going on. I never had this problem before with the previous version.

Source Image

[image]

Screen Shot from iPhone 4
[image]

Comment: It's not IPhone. Neither Iphone. It's iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable retina display if it's not already enabled:

```
[director enableRetinaDisplay:YES];
```

And provide the retina version of the background image using the "-hd" suffix.

backgroundImage.png (320 x 480 px)

backgroundImage-hd.png (640 x 960 px)

By the way you can set your own suffix:

```
#define CC_RETINA_DISPLAY_FILENAME_SUFFIX @"-hd"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , so what Image dimension should use I on Iphone - hd (640x960 px) and non hd (320x480 px)?

Comment: I got the answer from H2CO3 , believe it should be (640x960 px) and along with your suggestion it will work.Let me try.

Comment: Edited my answer for resolution info.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that iPhone 4 and 4S have retina displays - a display with a 4 times higher resolution as the previous models. Cocos2D, as opposed to iOS, doesn't use logical but physical screen sizes - you need to load another image with a 4 times higher resolution on iPhone 4 and 4S.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Do I really need to recreate the image with [(320x480 px) * 4] = 1280 * 1920? By doing this the image size gone up from 21 kb to 277 kb. I haven't tried to test it , let me try this in sometime.

Comment: @Anandh no. By increasing the size in both dimensions two times (i. e. 640 x 960), the overall resolution becomes four times higher.

Comment: @Anandh but hey, erkanyildiz has a better solution.